# Windows Store App standard icons not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm currently developing a Windows Store App for Windows 8.1 / Windows RT.

Some (or all) standard icons are not displayed correctly. For example the eye icon in a password field or the arrow in a combo box.

Here are two screenshots (sorry I don't have enough reputation to post images):

password field: https://i.stack.imgur.com/elTfb.png
combo box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1l1z.png

I used Calibri as font. With Segoe UI as font it's not much different, it's just a rectangle without the question mark iirc.

I just started developing the app and added the password field and combo box rather late, so I don't know if it ever worked correctly or if a change in the project caused this (like moving views (xaml + code-behind) into a view folder and changing the namespace accordingly).

What could be the cause of this? What should I check / try first?

Comment: Try by setting Stretch="None" UseLayoutRounding="True".

Comment: figured it out and will post an answer as soon as the 8 hour limit passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

At the beginning of the project I wanted to use Calibri system-wide.

In generic.xaml there's this:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="ContentControlThemeFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="SettingsFlyoutHeaderThemeFontFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily>
<FontFamily x:Key="SymbolThemeFontFamily">Segoe UI Symbol</FontFamily>
```

So I took that, put it in my App.xaml and replaced the fonts with Calibri to override the fonts app-wide. But of course, SymbolThemeFontFamily should stay Segoe UI **Symbol** and not be replaced by Calibri! So I deleted the line from my App.xaml and everything works fine.